# GCC: dereferencing ‘void *’ pointer while taking address

Tags: c, pointers, gcc, language-lawyer, void

I noticed GCC triggers:

```
warning: dereferencing ‘void *’ pointer
```

While taking the address of a dereferenced `void` expression like:

```
int main()
{
    void *p = "abcdefgh";

    printf("%p\n", p);
    printf("%p\n", &*p);

    return 0;
}
```

However, the expression `p` is equivalent to `&*p` according to the C standard:

> **§6.5.3.2 Address and indirection operators**
>
> The unary & operator returns the address of its operand. If the operand has type ‘‘type’’, the result has type ‘‘pointer to type’’. If the operand is the result of a unary * operator, neither that operator nor the & operator is evaluated and the result is as if both were omitted, except that the constraints on the operators still apply and the result is not an lvalue.

It is also important to know that Clang does not trigger this warning.

**DISCLAIMER**

For a better explanation, consider this:

```
int main()
{
    int *p = NULL;

    printf("%p\n", (void *) p);
    printf("%p\n", (void *) &*p);

    return 0;
}
```

This code compiles and runs perfectly with both Clang and GCC. The C standard is clear about `void` pointers, you can dereference them (thus getting a `void` value) but you cannot use the result of the expression.

Comment: It doesn't make sense to dereference a void pointer. The compiler doesn't know how much space the the thing the pointer is pointing to occupies.  If you cast it to the correct type, like `char *`, you will have better luck.

Comment: You missed the point. Read carefully and you will understand that here we aren’t dereferencing something, it might look like one semantically speaking, but it’s not.

Comment: It seems plausible for the compiler to implement the sequence `&*p` in two steps though.  First compute `*p`m and then take the address. That's what I mean.  So, the statement: `printf("%p\n", &*(char *)p);` would work.

Comment: What do you think about this: « Neither that operator (*) nor the the & operator is **evaluated** »

Comment: @bruceg C has a standard that specifies what compilers must do

Comment: This is a warning, not an error. Compilers are allowed to produce warnings on valid code.

Comment: Interesting, @interjay, can you provide a reference for this ?

Comment: @Prion That's mainly what warnings are for. If the code was invalid, it would have been an error instead. For example, many compilers will warn on `if (x=5)` even though it's perfectly valid. The standard says "An  implementation  may  generate  warnings  in  many  situations,  none  of  which  are
specified  as  part  of  this  International  Standard".

Comment: Interestingly, if you have `struct s *p = NULL;  printf("p=%p\n", &*p);`, where `struct s` is incomplete, gcc generates an error for this while clang compiles cleanly.  It looks like gcc is more strict when it comes to incomplete types.

Comment: Yes @dbush, I wrote it in my question, only GCC notices about this. I believe GCC warns more even if the code is valid, whiles Clang sticks to C standard violations.

Comment: @u238 It's not just warning on `void`, it's a full-on error on other incomplete types.  In my opinion, this is a defect in the standard and gcc is doing the "right" thing.

Comment: Why ? You can dereference a pointer to void in order to take its address, why should it be forbidden ?

Comment: @u238 of course compilers can warn about valid code, e.g. "unused variable" warnings (which Clang gives too, despite your claim it "sticks to C standard violations"). As well as Annex I (which interjay quoted) see footnote 9 in 5.1.2.3 "Of course, an implementation is free to produce any number of diagnostics as long as a valid program is still correctly translated." Since this is only a warning, and the program is correctly translated, GCC's behaviour conforms to the standard.

Comment: @JonathanWakely Is the warning a "diagnostic" message?

Comment: Yes, what else do you think it is?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I am assuming the question here is "Why is that?/What gives?".
In which case it's really a bit of a standards-wording / flexibility-for-compiler-developers issue.

Strictly speaking `*(void*)` is always bad, and the compiler is right to warn you.
In practice, as you rightly point out the pointer is never really actually dereferenced, in the evaluate what you see at what it points to way, so a naive implementation of a compiler would have no problem seeing this the way you do, and glossing over this and saying "pointers: they're numbers right? this one is 0xFFF....".

In practice though sometimes this is not the case. Sometimes compilers get pretty smart. No good examples spring to mind but that's not the point.

A couple of things I think might be worth noting with regards to "it's never evaluated":

The reason compilers are given the freedom to do what they want is partly to ease the process of compilation itself not just the output better implementations.
It may be that the next compiler you point this at will say no. Just because it's easier and it doesn't have to.

Secondly that's not really the point of warnings. If I saw this in a code review:

```
int i = 3;
if (3-i) {
    ((int*)(NULL)) += 4;
}
```

my reaction would *not* be: "Oh okay that's fine, its not evaluated." but "Whoa hang on a second: why?". This is what the compiler does too. It's telling you it thinks you are likely to have done something you might want to reconsider, in this case calling a `const char *` a `void *`. I, for one, agree with gcc.